# When do Fourier coefficients vanish in Hida families?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hida-theory

Suppose you have a Hida family with $q$-expansion $F = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(T) q^n$, where the coefficients $a_n(T)$ are power series in $\mathbb{Z}_p [[T]]$. Assume that $F$ is a cuspidal eigenform. If there exists an integer $n$ such that $a_n(T) = 0$, does $F$ have CM?

The converse is definitely true: if $F$ has CM by an imaginary quadratic field $K$, then $a_q(T)=0$ for all primes $q$ which are nonsplit in $K$. But I cannot think of any non-CM examples of Hida families which have a vanishing Fourier coefficient. Are there any such examples?

Comment: Can you not take $F$ to be supercuspidal at some prime dividing $n$?  Or twist by a ramified character?  (I don't know about Hida families.)

Comment: Kimball's construction can certainly be used to force $a_{n} = 0$ for all $n$ divisible by $\ell$, where $\ell$ is some prime *dividing* the level. But if we restrict to vanishing of $a_n$'s for $n$ coprime to the level of the Hida family then I don't know, and I think the question is a very interesting one.